# Choice of Clustered and Non-Clustered Index in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, indexing, create-table, clustered-index, non-clustered-index

I have two standalone tables `Person` and `Bank` in one database. Moreover I have a reference table `Customers` in another database.

Table: **Person**  - Database #1

```
PersonId (PK)       Name
_________________________________
1                   Ram
2                   Raj
3                   John
4                   Emma
```

Table: **Bank**  - Database #1

```
BankId (PK)      Name
_________________________________
1                ICICI
2                HDFC
3                SBI
```

Table: **Customers**  - Database #2

```
CustomerId (PK)   BankId    PersonId     UserName     PIN
_____________________________________________________________
1                   1         1           person1     7456bb
2                   1         4           person4     NULL
3                   2         1           person1     5691io
4                   3         2           person2     7892yh
5                   3         4           person4     1596pl
```

I need to execute the following queries efficiently, without **`INDEX`** it will do a **FULL COLUMN** search:

```
SELECT 
    c.CustomerId, p.Name, b.Name, c.UserName, c.PIN 
FROM 
    DB2.Customers c
INNER JOIN 
    DB1.Person p ON p.PersonId = c.PersonId 
INNER JOIN 
    DB1.Bank b ON b.BankId = c.BankId

SELECT * 
FROM DB2.Customers c 
WHERE c.UserName = 'person1'

SELECT * 
FROM DB2.Customers c 
WHERE c.UserName = 'person2' AND c.PIN = '7892yh'
```

So, I need a **CREATE** table SQL query for the table `Customers`. The following are the constraints

- `CustomerId` `int NOT NULL primary key`
- `BankId` `int NOT NULL` -- needs index and non-unique
- `PersonId` `int NOT NULL` -- needs index and non-unique
- `UserName` `varchar(25) NOT NULL` -- needs index and non-unique
- `PIN` `varchar(10) NULL` -- needs index and non-unique

The said table don't have a **FK** relationship because the said table is in different database server. So, I need a efficient table structure to fetch records using **JOIN**. I don't know the which INDEX is efficient in this scenario either **clustered** nor **non-clustered** index.

Comment: You already have a primary key (primary keys are clustered by default in SQL Server and you cannot have more than one clustered index on a table). If you are querying your table multiple times and not really using your current PK, one option is removing it and adding a different PK (e.g. perhaps one on bankid and personid if this combination is unique in your table).

Comment: @ZLK Here If I want Bank name and Person Name I use the following query `SELECT c.CustomerId, p.Name, b.Name, c.UserName, c.PIN FROM DB2.Customers c INNER JOIN DB1.Person p ON p.PersonId = c.PersonId INNER JOIN DB1.Bank b ON b.BankId = c.BankId` In this case I need efficient `JOIN`. So, I planning to add an Index for `BankId` as well as rest of the columns which is listed above.

Comment: Adding an index on each individual column isn't efficient and won't work how you expect it to. SQL Server only picks one index when you query a table (whatever the optimiser thinks is the most efficient one unless you force a particular index). EDIT: I actually don't think you really need an additional index on your table with a query like that, now that I think about it. SQL optimiser should use the PKs on all three tables well enough already.

Comment: @ZLK - I modified the question little bit. The above said three queries, I calling often.